# 2 Seperate Freight Costs for local delivery and rural delivery areas

Tags: shipping

Normal delivery cost $4 but couriers deliver to rural areas for $7
need seperate option for customer to click

When customer is asked to input freight method ,at the moment there is 1 option for $4
i need another option for customer if there delivery is a rural delivery address
How can i achieve this?

thanks
malcolm

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would query some API your shipping company has made available. For two reasons:

1. No matter your opinion about what qualifies as rural, the shipping company will bill you based on their definition.
2. Other factors may apply and these APIs will request all relevant information and give you a price based on that.

Comment: +1 Use your Shipping company rate calculator, it's sometimes seemingly arbitrary what is rural/local. They have the database so they're the authority.